# How to fetch more than 1 Entity at once on Core Data using UISearchBar and NSFetchedResultsController in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hey guys I have this app that uses Core Data and NsFetchedResultsController and I am using a searchBar to search attributes within 3 entities.

Problem is each entity have the different attributes, naturally. But I want to search all 3 Entities at once with the same searchBar input from the user.

All 3 Entities have an attribute "name" and the idea is to search all Entities that have the searchBar string contained in the "name" attribute.

So far I can only search for 1 Entity since I am using this code:

```
// MARK: - Fetched results controller
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.

     let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}


// MARK: - Search
var searchController: UISearchController? = nil

func reloadFRC(predicate: NSPredicate?) {
    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    performFecth()
}

//Delegate: UIsearchController
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        var predicate: NSPredicate?
        if searchBarText != "" {
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchBarText)
        }
        self.reloadFRC(predicate)
    }
}


//Delegate: UISearchBar
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.reloadFRC(nil)
}


//Configure Search
func configureSearch() {
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    if let _searchController = self.searchController {
        _searchController.delegate = self
        _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        _searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        _searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = Utils.colorFromHex(0x2FC5DA)
        _searchController.searchBar.tintColor = Utils.colorFromHex(0x585858)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar
    } else {print("ERROR configuring _searchController in %@", #function)}
}
```

So, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `_fetchedResultsController` anymore, it goes against almost every Swift coding style. Also, you can replace the nil check and instead use the `lazy` modifier. Is there a specific reason you want to make it `lazy` instead of just initializing it normally? If this is a search screen, it seems like 99.9% of the time, it would get initialized.

Now on to your entity problem. Make all 3 of the entities inherit from a single parent entity. This parent entity would contain the `name` attribute. You would then make a fetch for the parent entity and it will correctly search through all of the child entities.

You can also get them sectioned by entity by passing in `entity.name` for `.sectionNameKeyPath` of the `NSFetchedResultsController` initializer function. If you decide to go this route, you will also need to sort by `entity.name` as well, so it knows how to order the sections.

Comment: So I should remove the the "name " attribute from all 3 entities and put inside the Parent entity? I don´t get how the search would access the object names from the Parent entity.

Comment: Also how could I keep adding objects to each Entity if the attribute was transfered to Search? Because as I said, each entity have the "name" attribute and the user need to create objects within each Entity. So, if I remove the "name" from the 3 entities and put  into the Parent Entity, I how would the adding work on the 3 entities? Do you understand my point?

Comment: Child entities inherit all attributes from their parent entity. So any attributes (`name`) defined for the parent entity will also be defined for child entities.

This is explained in the inheritance section of: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html

Comment: But I am not understanding is how to code all that. I have created an Entity called "Search" and set it as parent for the other 3. I generated the subclasses again but I have no idea of how I could implement the search functionality in code. Could you help me @bsmith11?